# how to call to a controller action from the php template in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Good morning 
As iam new to symfony you have been helping a lot to me i heartfully thank you

In my sucess.html.php
I get the session variable

```
$var=$app->getSession()->get('id');

//Now iam checking whether the variable is set or not 
if(!isset($var))
{
  //here i need to call to a controller for a particular action
}
```

i used the e`cho $view['actions']->render('RepairLoginBundle:Login:login');`

it is showing me no route found for Login:login

Comment: I think that calling controller action from view its not correct for MVC. May be you need use view helper?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the render action.

In your view , you can do

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php echo $view['actions']->render(
        new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference('RepairLoginBundle:Login:login', array())
    ) ?>
</div>
```

The above code calls `RepairLoginBundle:Login:login` controller from the view

Documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html (see PHP tab)

Comment: <div id="sidebar">
    <?php echo $view['actions']->render(new ControllerReference('RepairLoginBundle:Login:login',)) ?>
</div> i used the code what you said in this way but it is throwing error Class 'Controller Reference' not found

Comment: i modified the code and used in this way                                 <?php echo $view['actions']->render(new ControllerReference('RepairLoginBundle:Login:login',)) ?>                but it is throwing me the error Class 'Controller Reference' not found

Comment: try add use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference; with the use statements

Comment: or you can do <?php echo $view['actions']->render(new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference('RepairLoginBundle:Login:login',)) ?>

Comment: thank you my problem is cleared but a little problem has erased i.e i used if(!isset($var)) i called to controller from there to view. if the variable is set it will display the below html page.       The problem is  even if the variable is not set it is displaying both views if you can solve my problem plaese say me i will explain you in detail